# How can I parse "1:15 P.M." into a NodaTime LocalTime?

Tags: c#, nodatime

Parsing "1:15 pm" is easy:

```
var pattern = LocalTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("h:mm tt");
var time = pattern.Parse("1:15 pm").Value;
```

However, this doesn't work with the similar forms "1:15 P.M.", "1:15 PM", or "1:15 p.m."

Is there any built in support for those other forms of am/pm specifier, or does it need to be handled with string pre-processing?

Comment: FYI - The BCL doesn't support the other forms either.

Comment: @JamesWorld DateTime.Parse actually supports "PM", but not "p.m." or "P.M."

Comment: first modify the string by using replacing the values that you dont want like string s=timestring.replace("P.M","PM").replace("p.m.","PM") and so on

Comment: Just do this instead: `var time = pattern.Parse(("1:15 pm").Replace(".", "").ToLower()).Value;`. This should satisfy all your test runs.

Comment: "1:15 PM" works for me with exactly your code. If it's not working for you, what version of Noda Time are you using?

Comment: Do you still have any issues with this, or did my solution fix it for you? (Just on a Noda Time dev kick at the moment, so if it's still broken for you I'd like to work out why.)

Comment: I went back to the code causing the problem and tried to reproduce the "PM" parse failure, but I wasn't able to do so. I think that was likely an error on my part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, the "1:15 PM" version should work already - it does for me.

If you want to allow "P.M" or "p.m". you'll need to create a culture with appropriate AM/PM signifiers. That's easy enough to do:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using NodaTime.Text;
using NodaTime;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var culture = (CultureInfo) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
        culture.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator = "a.m.";
        culture.DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator = "p.m.";
        string text = "1:15 P.M.";
        var pattern = LocalTimePattern.Create("h:mm tt", culture);
        var value = pattern.Parse(text).Value;
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }   
}
```

However, note that at this point, `pm` and `am` *won't* work - if you need to handle both formats, you'll need to create multiple patterns and see which one (if any) parses the text successfully.